# How do I connect to MySQL database via Powershell?

Tags: mysql, powershell, invoke

I was trying to get Powershell connect to a MySQL database from a remote location.

What I've tried before: (https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1899615-powershell-command-to-connect-to-remote-sql-server)

```
Function DBConnection
(
    [string]$server,
    [string]$database,
    [string]$dbuser,
    [string]$dbpass,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Query,
    [switch]$IntegratedSecurity,
    [int]$QueryTimeout = 120
)
{
    #$secdbpass = ConvertTo-SecureString $dbpass -AsPlainText -Force
    if (-not ($IntegratedSecurity))
    {   
        #$secdbpass = ConvertTo-SecureString $dbpass -AsPlainText -Force
        #$connString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;user id=$dbuser;password=$secdbpass;Connect Timeout=$QueryTimeout;"
        $connString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;user id=$dbuser;password=$dbpass;Connect Timeout=$QueryTimeout;"
    }
    Else
    {   $connString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout=$QueryTimeout;"
    }
    
    $dataAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

    $dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand ($query,$connString)
    $commandBuilder = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder $dataAdapter
    $dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
    [void]$dataAdapter.fill($dt)
    $dt
}
DBConnection -server 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306' -database 'xxx' -dbuser 'xxx' -dbpass 'xxx' -Query 'INSERT INTO xxx (xxx, xxx) VALUES ("xxx", "xxx")'
```

And I got this result:

```
Exception when calling "Fill" with 1 argument (s): "Network-related or instance-specific error connecting to SQL Server. The server was not found or is inaccessible. Check that the
Instance name is correct and whether SQL Server allows remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - connection string invalid) "
In line: 28 characters: 2
+ [void] $ dataAdapter.fill ($ dt)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId: SqlException
```

I also tried this solution:

(https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/03/02/querying-mysql-databases.aspx/)

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'xxx' -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('xxx',$password)
Connect-MySqlServer -Port "3306"  -Credential $credential -ComputerName 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' -Database "xxx"
Invoke-MySqlQuery  -Query 'INSERT INTO xxx (xxx, xxx) VALUES ("xxx", "xxx")'
```

And this was my result:

```
Connect-MySqlServer: Exception when calling "Open" with 0 argument (s): "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."
In line: 4 characters: 1
+ Connect-MySqlServer -Port "3306" -Credential $ credential -ComputerNa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException, Connect-MySqlServer
 

PS C: \ Users \ Administrator>
```

How do I connect to a MySQL database via Powershell?

Comment: Have you verified that it's actually listening on port 3306 (and not some non-standard port?)

Comment: yess. its a webhosting from netcup - preinstalled database service

Comment: Well, the first attempt fails because you're using code meant for connecting to an SQL Server (Microsoft's proprietary SQL db engine != mysql). The second one should work, maybe open a ticket with your hosting provider?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen _Well, the first attempt fails because you're using code meant for connecting to an SQL Server (Microsoft's proprietary SQL db engine != mysql)"_ I was already expecting it. I will open a ticket. but Thx

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen they said I use the internal ip, rip last 8h